# Optimize Searching method in File at Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, optimization, refactoring

I am trying to optimize the method below. It is the core of my project(as the % of time in the method is close to 95%). It reads a line of file and if the tid is in the line it returns the first number, which is the document id. A few lines of the file for example:

```
5168  268:0.0482384162801528 297:0.0437108092315354 352:0.194373864228161
5169  268:0.0444310314892627 271:0.114435072663748 523:0.0452228057908503
```

The current implementation uses the method tid_add_colon_in_front(tid) as the tid is just a string, and the did_tids_file is the file that has the data (has been opened already)

Any ideas as to how I can improve it any further will be welcome!

```
def dids_via_tid(tid) -> set:
    did_tids_file.seek(0)
    dids = set()

    #To find the term ids in the file
    tid = tid_add_colon_in_front(tid)
    did_str = ""

    #Τo not do line.split
    for line in did_tids_file:
      did_str = ""

      if tid in line:
        for char in line:
          if char == " ":
            break
          did_str += char

        dids.add(did_str)
    return dids
```

My previous implementation was with line.split, which return's a list and by my current knowledge is heavier in memory and time when dealing with very big amounts of data.

Also, I have tried reading data from the file with the readLine as below, but it didnt improve the performance

```
line = myFile.readLine()
while line:
 #Do work
 line = myFile.readLine()
```

Comment: So what is `tid`? For example `0.0482384162801528` ?

Comment: Looping in python is always going to be slower than looping in C. `line.parition(' ')` is going to be better. And unless your individual lines are millions of characters, it's not gonna have a noticeable memory impact.

Comment: Are you calling this method repeatedly with different `tid` parameters? Is there a reason you aren't precomputing a mapping of tid -> dids? How large is the input file? dozens of lines? thousands? millions?

Comment: @AndrejKesely a tid is the value of the string before a ":" and after is the weight (which is irrelevant in my case). For example: in the line of the file:

5168  268:0.0482384162801528 297:0.0437108092315354

5168 is the document id which is for example a Stack overflow question,
268 is a term id, for example the python tag in this question and 0.0482384162801528 is the weight

Comment: @MegaIng yes, the tid parameters are all different. One of my thoughts is to actualy precompute the tids, and will be my next step if I can't optimize it further. The file is quite big actually, as it has hundred thousands of lines.

Comment: @gybonel So for your usecase it probably isn't acceptable to load more or less the entire file into memory at once, right? Otherwise this could be made very efficientwith a dictionary like cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple `tids` that you are looking for, you 100% should be searching for them all during 1 pass through the file.  It will be much faster if your file size is 100K plus lines.

```
# tid line finder

import re
from collections import defaultdict


def tid_searcher(filename, tids_of_interest):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename, 'r') as src:
        for line in src:
            line_tids = set(re.findall(r'(\d+):', line)) # re:  group of one or more digits followed by colon
            hits = tids_of_interest & line_tids  # set intersection
            if hits:
                line_no = re.search(r'\A\d+', line).group(0) # re: one or more digits at start of string
                for hit in hits:
                    res[hit].append(line_no)

    return res

tids_of_interest = {'268', '271'}
filename = 'data.txt'

print(tid_searcher(filename, tids_of_interest))

# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'268': ['5168', '5169'], '271': ['5169']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regular expressions (`re` module) to speed up the search:

```py
import re


def dids_via_tid(f, tid):
    return {m.group(1) for line in f if (m := re.match(rf"(\d+).*\b{tid}:", line))}


with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    print(dids_via_tid(f_in, "271"))
```

Prints:

```
{'5169'}
```

The `your_file.txt` contains:

```
5168  268:0.0482384162801528 297:0.0437108092315354 352:0.194373864228161
5169  268:0.0444310314892627 271:0.114435072663748 523:0.0452228057908503
```